# Django markup templatetags error

Tags: python, django, markup

I am getting the following errors in a django app:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'markup' is not a valid tag library: Template library markup not found, tried django.templatetags.markup,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.markup
```

I have tried to following the solutions form [this website](https://github.com/rossp/django-helpdesk/issues/44) which suggests that that 'django.contrib.markup' is missing from the INSTALLED_APPS list, but I already have it there.

I can `import markdown` from `python manage.py shell` so it is installed and is in the path.

I am using Django 1.3.

Here is the template:

```
{% load markup %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
...
```

I just tried it again, and it works.  Odd.  I tried restarting the server before submitting the question, but I am not sure what is different now.

Comment: Try calling `render_to_response` from `python manage.py shell` on the template in question, and please give a clip of the template file in question. Are you using `{% extends %}`?

Comment: If you submit an answer I will give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `render_to_response` from `python manage.py shell` on the template in question, and please give a clip of the template file in question.

Fixed itself?  Spooky. I hate those "fixes" because there's no guarantee that it won't break again or that the same "fix" will work again.

The only things I can think of there are:

- Something had the old version cached
- There was an old .pyc file laying around
- Your server was trying to be clever
- WSGI didn't reload the code or templates after you changed it

Comment: I am getting this error too. Any insight into why? Is there an easier way to fix it? I don't really understand how to do this from the shell.