# 'markup_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: python, django, pinax

Everytime I add a particular object to my database (this only affects one particular app on my site), I get the TemplateSyntaxError 'markup_tags' is not a valid tag library.

Specifically, it cannot load this: {% load markup_tags %}. But this is strange because when I open a Django shell and `import markup` all is fine.

This question has been asked before on StackOverflow here: [Django markup templatetags error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399649/django-markup-templatetags-error/6400140#comment14486841_6400140)

However, I don't understand *why* this is happening and I don't really understand how to fix it. They said render_to_response the template. But I'm not sure exactly how I would do this from the shell (Django noob here).

[image]

Comment: `markup_tags` is located in a filed `markup_tags.py`, not a module called `markup` (so `import markup` tells you nothing).

Comment: Sorry meant markdown -- that's what it said in the other post. Still means nothing?

Comment: Do you really get a load error or is the markup simply failing on that particular object?

Comment: did you add `django_markup` or whatever app that you are using that provides `markup_tags` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, it's `django.contrib.markup`, and it's installed there

Comment: And I added a screenshot of the exact issue.

Comment: Note that `django.contrib.markup` is deprecated and history by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was actually not properly importing the module into into my project that contained `markup_tags`. While the library was available in my environment, in my `settings.py` I did not properly reference it. Dumb mistake, but might help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Consider trying `{% load markup %}` in your template.

Comment: This is now very very out of date. django.contrib.markup is no longer included but they have created a separate repo for it. Here are the docs: https://django-markup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/